# SQL Server Azure DB Syntax\Schema issue

Tags: sql-server, database

I wrote a simple query to check the existence of a column, if the column exists then do stuff with that column, else don't do stuff.

I developed the query on a standard on-premise SQL Server, and it works great! If column `MickeyMouse` does not exist in the table `Disneyland`, it returns "Column MickeyMouse does not exist".

Now that I execute against an Azure DB it seems to check the schema if the column exists in parts of the code that is not applicable due to the if exists resulting in false.

I get an error column 'MickeyMouse' does not exist, due to the reference in the true block. Is there a different way to do this in azure DB?

Sample:

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM sys.columns
        WHERE Name = N'MickeyMouse'
            AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.DisneyLand')
        )

    BEGIN
    DECLARE @TEST DATETIME = (SELECT TOP 1 MickeyMouse FROM DisneyLand)
    SELECT 'Column MickeyMouse exists'
    END

ELSE

    BEGIN
    SELECT 'Column MickeyMouse does not exist'
    END
```

If I remove the reference to mickeymouse column in the true block, the strings return as expected.

Comment: It will fail in on prem too if the table already exists. The only time this will succeed (if the table doesn't contain that column) is if the batch itself creates the table - then the compilation of the statement will be deferred

Comment: The True and False blocks on this query work on my On Prem Server, its only in Azure I get the error for when the column does not exist.

Comment: Or the other circumstance where this script will succeed will be if the whole table doesn't exist. But if the table already exists at the start of the execution of this batch and doesn't have that column then compilation will fail in on prem too - as shown here in SQL Express https://dbfiddle.uk/KSBiEi2_

Comment: The table does exist on azure DB it is just missing the column, same scenario as on Prem

Comment: It presumably doesn't actually pre-exist in on prem in the database you are testing - to repeat if the table already exists at the start of the execution of this batch and doesn't have that column then compilation will fail in on prem too. So either the table doesn't exist at the start of the batch or it has the column

Comment: Odd, I assure you it does work on my on prem test server.  Table DisneyLand exists but column MickeyMouse does not exist.  Query compiles and runs returning false statement.  Is there a different way to do an if column exists, then do stuff with that column?

Comment: Seems like you've discovered Deferred Name Resolution. Have a read through Kendra's article, [Gotchas with Deferred Name Resolution in SQL Server: Stored Procedures, Synonyms, Views, and Functions](https://littlekendra.com/2021/10/18/deferred-name-resolution-in-sql-server-stored-procedures-views-functions/), and take note of all the `Msg 207` errors in each "Table or view exists but doesn’t have the column listed" section. Almost certainly when you were testing with your on-prem server the table did not exist, or it existed with the column. I tested the error throws on SQL Servers 2012-2022.

Comment: If you need to conditionally execute code based on the existence of a column you'll want to wrap that column-specific code in a nested function/procedure, or invoke it via [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why ssms won't compile the query for azure DB when it does for on premis sql, but I found clues that if I make the query to do stuff to the column that is or isn't there a dynamic query it compiles and works as it should.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).